# Get current URL with selenium

Tags: url, selenium, junit

## Hello

I would like to get the current url of the page after a click on link. When I click on the link (of the 1rst page), the link open a new page (2nd page), and I want get the url of the 2nd page but when I call GetCurrentUrl(), the method return the url of the first page.

This is my code :

```
String att = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Lien 2")).getAttribute("href");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Lien 2")).click(); // Open a the 2nd page
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String act = driver.getCurrentUrl(); // Return the url of the 1rst page; but I want the 2nd
System.out.println("act "+act+" att "+att);
assertEquals(act, att);
```

Thanks very much for the help !

Comment: When you say 'Open a 2nd page' do you mean it opens a second window/tab?

Comment: yes, a second tab in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the change to `pageloadTimeout()`, try *manually* waiting for the Url to change (this is what I'm doing in my code so thought I'd answer).

- Insert the function definition below into your code.
- The function prints the current URL in a loop so its helpful to debug any problems.
- Change the value "30" in `WebDriverWait(driver, 30))` if you want a longer timeout.

Make sure to call the function as follows:

```
try {
    waitForUrl(the-url-you-want-to-wait-for);
} catch (Exception ex) {
//handle exception
}
```

Function:

```
/**
 * Wait until the current page's URL changes to whatever you specify.
 * @param Url The URL you want to wait for.
 */
protected static void waitForUrl(WebDriver driver, final String Url) throws Exception {
    try {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                                    System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl());
                return d.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().endsWith(Url);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        throw new Exception("Timeout Exception encountered while waiting for URL " + Url + ": \n" + e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you increase my reputation please because I can't answer without 10 reputation ?